# Custom Circular Menu Android

Tags: android

I want to create a circular like the image below.
Any idea of how can i achieve that?

Thank you.

[Circular Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blrWd.png)

Comment: Shall I Google it for you? `android circular menu`

Answer (score 0):

Let me Google that for you: [Android Circular Menu](http://bfy.tw/2HEI)

May be you are looking for : **[ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)**

You just have to write like:

```
ArcMenu menu = (ArcMenu) findViewById(R.id.arc_menu);

final int itemCount = ITEM_DRAWABLES.length;
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
    item.setImageResource(ITEM_DRAWABLES[i]);

    final int position = i;
    menu.addItem(item, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });// Add a menu item
}
```